# Getting an error in an OpenCV project (Project to recognize the face of a person using LBPH)

Tags: python, opencv

I am making a project to recognize the person by his/her face using OpenCV library in Python.
My code is :-

```
# Import OpenCV and sys libraries
import cv2
import sys
import os
import numpy as np

subjects = ["", "Daksh", "Ishika", "Dashya", "Shivang"]

#Create the haar cascade
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
def draw_rectangle(img, rect):
    (x, y, w, h) = rect
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
def draw_text(img, text, x, y):
    cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
def imgdetect(gray,image):
#Detect faces in the image
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        
    #Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
        roi_color = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        return image



#for video capturing
vidCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    # To capture video frame by frame
    _, image = vidCapture.read()

    #monochrome image capturing (color to gray)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    subjects = ["Daksh", "Ishika", "Shivang", "Dashya"]
    canvas = imgdetect(gray, image)
    gray, rect = detect_face(image)
    label = face_recognizer.predict(gray)
    label_text = subjects[label]
        
    #draw a rectangle around face detected
    draw_rectangle(canvas, rect)
    #draw name of predicted person
    draw_text(canvas, label_text, rect[0], rect[1]-5)

    cv2.imshow("Attendence....", canvas)
    
    #To break control by pressing 'q'
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            break

#Release after processing is done
vidCapture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But, I am getting the following error while proceeding with the code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13428/371309763.py in <module>
     40     canvas = imgdetect(gray, image)
     41     img, rect = detect_face(image)
---> 42     label = face_recognizer.predict(img)
     43     label_text = subjects[label]
     44 

error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:250: error: (-215:Assertion failed) s >= 0 in function 'cv::setSize'
```

I am unable to understand the error message.
Why am I getting this error and what can be the possible fixes for the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (s >= 0) in setSize - while trying to place an image over a webcam feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098698/opencv-error-assertion-failed-s-0-in-setsize-while-trying-to-place-an-im)